# Compare Backup Files

Tags: database, bash, shell, unix

I have scripts to transfer backup files (from a PostgreSQL database) from a server to another and to process these files (The OS of these servers is Ubuntu Server 14). Before processing these files I need to check if they were fully sent, and I check it by comparing the size of the file with an old version of this file (the new file should always be bigger), I get file size by using the command `stat -c %s "$File"`.

The problem happens when few things changed on the server and the backup file is right, but a little bit smaller than his older version, because of that the other script doesn't process the file and that should not happen.

My question is mostly theoretical, I want to know is if there is a better way to compare these two files in order to be sure that the file is not corrupted or incomplete, without making too much effort (restoring the database).

Comment: If you want to compare two files to see if they are different you can do what everyone on the internet does, create a hashsum (e.g. MD5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the equality of the hash values of the transferred file on the two servers. If they are equal, the file was transferred successfully. For example for md5sum you can do:

```
# md5sum myfilename
e933c63f33dab322bb545ef93a712c62 myfilename
```